# Outline edition tool in CorelDraw?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, corel-draw

Is there any tool in CorelDraw X4/X5 that allows to change the outline [like you can do in Illustrator](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=p_NHXuSIOV8#t=424s)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes

**Outline Pen Tool** in the Toolbox, where you can change anything regarding outline.